# String Encoding TextView.setText()

Tags: java, android, encoding, textview

while setting text in a TextView, the character 'ù' isn't correctly interpreted. This is my code:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
String s;
byte[] bytes;
s = "dgseùeT41ù";
bytes = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
tv.setText(new String(bytes));
```

I don't know where I'm failing. Thank you for support

Comment: I do not know the problem but all I know is that it can solved by using a string resource instead

Comment: @Pietro:: I have tried setting a `TextView` with `setText(s)` using s = "dgseùeT41ù"; and it is being displayed correctly on my device.

Comment: @Barns52 its nice thing. Some people would have downvoted it!

Answer (score 2):

You have used `"ISO-8859-1"` but java uses by default `UTF-8` so either define the charset while creating string

[From docs](http://From%20docs)

> Case mapping is based on the Unicode Standard version specified by the
>   Character class and A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format

so

```
bytes = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
tv.setText(new String(bytes,"ISO-8859-1"));
```

or don't use it at all

```
bytes = s.getBytes();
tv.setText(new String(bytes));
```

Comment: How comes the answer had `System.out.println` is it a copy and paste. You may need to put a link of original post!

Comment: @Xenolion so judgmental , i was testing it on online java portal,, tada

Comment: Okay got yah! Sorry!