# TextView is not showing some characters

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi i read a Bluetooth Input Stream from my uC, it sends "°" characters. But textView dosnt show it correctly. How can i force TextView to use ISO-8859-2?

This is my textvie call:

```
//set listener for listen for the incoming data from the microcontroller
    bluetoothMC.setOnDataReceivedListener(object : BluetoothMC.onDataReceivedListener {
        override fun onDataReceived(data: String) {
            timln_view.append(data)
            writeFile("timeline.txt", data)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String Encoding TextView.setText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083800/string-encoding-textview-settext)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String text = "your text here"
bytes[] bytes;

bytes = text.getBytes("ISO-8859-2");
textView.setText(new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-2"));
```